# Time needed to run reformatvob

Tags: linux, clearcase

I have to upgrade our VOBs with `reformatvob`.
I'm trying to estimate how long that should take. I know it depends on VOB size and hardware, but I'm trying to know if there are any rules that could tell me the process time per 1GB of VOB?

We use Linux VOB server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to estimate the length of a [`reformatvob`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_reformatvob.htm).
And that time can vary between a `refortvob -dump` and a `reformatvob -load`.
As described in [this thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000004953316), it can be quite heavy one CPU, memory and disk resources.

The best approach is to guesstimate by doing a reformatvob on a small vob, and see if that scale on a larger vob (everything else being identical: same server, same local disk, ...)

If `reformatvob` doesn't work, you also have [`db_dumper` and `db_loader`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21172574).